# Weird future Adobe Flash Player version

Tags: flash-player

Are beta versions not marked? I don't remember installing a beta. Pic taken today (same as days ago):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is the latest version of flash. It was auto updated by the Flash updater service. The main flash site itself is not updated but http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html has mentioned 11.3.300.270

[image]